# Why is the sum of squares of the edges of any tetrahedron four times the sum of squares of lines joining the midpoints of opposite edges?

Tags: vectors

**Question.** The problem states that "Using vectors, or otherwise, prove that the sum of the squares of the edges of any tetrahedron equals four times the sum of the squares of the lines joining the midpoints of opposite edges". For "opposite edges", I understand it as adjacent edges on the same face.

---

**My Attempt.**

Let $\vec x_i$ where $i=1,2,3,4$ be the position vectors of the four vertices of the tetrahedron.

Then $$\sum_{j,k} {\vert \vec x_j - \vec x_k \vert}^2$$ is the sum of squares of the tetrahedron's edges, where $j,k$ are all the 4 choose 2 combinations out of the set of $i$.

For the other sum of squares, if we visualize it, every line segment connecting midpoints of opposite edges should be half of one particular $\vert \vec x_j - \vec x_k \vert$ by similar triangles; there are twelve such line segments, and every two of them are related to one single edge since each edge is adjacent to two faces. Hence, the sum of squares is $$\sum_{j,k} {(\frac 12\vert \vec x_j - \vec x_k \vert})^2\times2$$.

Thus it was obvious to me that the first sum is twice the second sum, rather than four times. So is the problem wrong?

---

**Comment.** Any kind of hint or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Opposite edges" means edges that don't share a vertex. So if the tetrahedron's vertices are a,b,c,d, then the three pairs of opposite edges are ab&cd, ac&bd, ad&bc. Your approach using the position vectors of the vertices should work.

Comment: Use vector operations to express midpoints and distances, and remember that $|x|^2=x\cdot x$ and the dot product is bilinear, so algebraically it works a lot like multiplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Karl. Especially for your second comment, showing that you indeed delved into the question as well as your kindness. This question is more interesting than I thought it was. I just solved it with quite a few algebra. Thanks a lot again! <3 @Karl

Comment: By the way, please copy and paste your two comments as an answer to my posted question, and I am giving it a green check. Thanks. @Karl